# css align vertically specific divs

Tags: css, css-float

I currently have the following html:

```
<div>objA</div>
<div class="tower">objB</div>
<div class="tower">objC</div>
<div class="tower">objD</div>
<div>objE</div>
<div>objF</div>
<div>objG</div>
<div>objH</div>
<div>objI</div>
<div>objJ</div>
```

I'd like to tower(align vertically) the divs in class "tower" so that the following image can be reproduced:

[image: "div-tower"]

Instead, what I currently have is the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/kAMB5/

Are there any ways in which I could go about achieving my wanted result purely through css? (preferably without changing the html content)

**UPDATE**: You can assume these are fixed width divs.

Comment: Can we assume they are fixed width divs?

Comment: I don't think you can archive this without changing the HTML content, unless you're only targeting this very specific situation (i.e. fixed dimension).

Comment: You need to put objC and objD divs inside objB div like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kAMB5/3/ to achieve desired structure

Comment: This could work http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/kAMB5/5/, although it involves changing the `div` to `ul` and `li`

Comment: @AlexW Yes, you can. I'll write that up in my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra `div` wrapping your `.tower` as in: http://jsfiddle.net/kAMB5/4/

Apart from that, CSS Grid Layout (IE10) or on your `.tower` CSS3 flexbox (still need a container I guess) could achieve the same result but with lesser compatibility

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I liked this idea best since it keeps independence between the `.tower` divs hence preventing the css properties in `.tower` from piling up on one and other. I could also keep the `.tower` divs tracked in a simple array if I keep my nodes structured this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to put objC and objD divs inside objB div like this: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kAMB5/3) to achieve desired result:

**HTML:**

```
<div>objA</div>
<div>
    objB
    <div class="tower">objC</div>
    <div class="tower">objD</div>
</div>
<div>objE</div>
<div>objF</div>
<div>objG</div>
<div>objH</div>
<div>objI</div>
<div>objJ</div>
```

Comment: You can't control anymore `border`, `padding-bottom` or `margin-bottom` on *objB* with this structure. Keeping it in `.tower` allows for that